# Rails devise having multiple fields in sign up form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am designing an app where the user signs up using the devise gem (email + password).

Then, i have a form to capture other personal information and since i am creating something like a social dating app i need to match users using this data.

My question is based on a design concern because I created a Model with devise and then I am using a different database to hold the data coming from the form after sign up.

Do you suggest having a mutual column between Model from Devise and the new Database, maybe Id or email since they are both unique

OR

Ask for this information in the sign up for by overwrite devise using a custom controller?

What is considered best practise?  Keep in mind that I have two types of users, it is not males/females, it is something else, therefore Maybe two databases are helpful having another one from devise so in total 3.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to go would be to keep the Devise model for the users and then create another model (for example "Profile"), where you can store all the more "personal" data for each user.

Then you can either ask for the user to fill that data through a new form, or you can create nested fields in the sign up form where the user can fill some information right away.

Comment: Can you provide example with code on how you can combine fields and relations?  I use devise with a model called Users, then how can I relate the id or the email which are both unique to another table containing personal information about the user. Do i need to name this table with another name like for example new users or active users etc?

Comment: Let's say you create a new model, called Profile. In your profile migration file you add a column "user_id". Then in your user model you add a line `has_one :profile` and in your Profile model you add `belongs_to :user`. Now when you create a profile you pass the user id in the params and after it saves you can do `user.profile` and get the profile for that user. Or even `profile.user`. I would suggest watching this railscast for nested forms: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
Good luck! :)